# ngx-admin error when using multiple popovers

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5, nebular

I am using ngx-admin NbPopover,
4 attachments per page. I want to close the event when the event is finished.

```
@ViewChild (NbPopoverDirective) popverDirective: NbPopoverDirective;
this.popverDirective.hide();
```

I can only use one of them. others are not working.
Could your help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple NbPopoeverDirectives you can get them with @ViewChildren so try the follwing code:

```
@ViewChildren(NbPopoeverDirective) popovers: QueryList<NbPopoeverDirective>;

...

hidePopups(){
  if(this.popovers){
     this.popovers.forEach(popover => {
        popove.hide();
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple NbPopoverDirective, you can add a selector over the element holding the directive, and use the "read" option of @ViewChild to get the NbPopoverDirective

Component.html:

```
<nb-action #transferAction [nbPopover]="transferPopoverComponent"></nb-action>
<nb-action #orderAction  [nbPopover]="orderPopoverComponent"></nb-action>
```

Component.ts:

```
  @ViewChild("transferAction", { read: NbPopoverDirective }) transferPopover: NbPopoverDirective;
  @ViewChild("orderAction", { read: NbPopoverDirective }) orderPopover: NbPopoverDirective;
```

See how we tag the nb-actions with "#transferAction" and use this to select the ViewChild, then read the inner directive